# How Do I Find the Index of An Element Within an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have html similar to the following

```
<ul>
  <li> hi </li>
  <li> hoi </li>
  <li> privyet </li>
  <li class="selected"> bonjour </li>
  <li> hallo </li>
</ul>
```

and I use jQuery to get all the `li` elements in the `ul`

```
$("ul li")
```

how can I get the index of the `li` element with the class `selected` within the jQuery array of `li` elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var index = $("ul li.selected").index();
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/xXT9r/

Comment: Good answer. +1 for the jsfiddle example, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

With index: 
http://api.jquery.com/index/

> Description: Search for a given
>   element from among the matched
>   elements.

```
// Text
$("ul li.selected").index("ul li");
```

Thx patrick

```
// jQuery object
$('ul li.selected');
var index = $("ul li").index(elem);

// search Within siblings
$("ul li.selected").index();
```

All 3 demos:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXT9r/4/

Comment: Ghommey - I'm talking about your updated answer. I gave you a link to test it. I think you were thinking of this: `var elem = $('ul li.selected');var index = $("ul li").index(elem);` http://jsfiddle.net/xXT9r/3/

Comment: Yes you are right - I updated it so it works now and will add your sample.

Comment: Yes, looks like you've got it now.

Answer (score 2):

To me, if you've already done the `$("ul li")`, then you want to avoid doing it again (if you *haven't* already done it, I'd definitely go with [patrick's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150982/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-element-within-an-array/3151010#3151010)). Let's say you stored that jQuery object as `items`. You'd do this:

```
var pos = items.index(items.filter(".selected"));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk3Aj/ (blatantly stole patrick's and updated :-) )

This uses the second variant of [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

Again, this is useful if you've already done the `$("ul li")` part.

Comment: T.J. - Good point. The question did imply that it is starting with the entire set. +1